# How does a dictionary get passed byref to a Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, generic-collections

I have the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, WSResponse> responseDictionary = new Dictionary<string, WSResponse>();
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
foreach (string ID in IDs)
{
      string localID = ID;

      Task newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
           WSResponse response = Query.GetListFor(localID);                    
           responseDictionary.Add(localID, response);
      });
      taskList.Add(newTask);
}

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

On the server where this code is running, our IT team has server monitoring software, and they told us that the software reports that an `unsafe static Dictionary` is being passed around. My guess is that when I use the Dictionary inside a Task, the dictionary is passed to the Task thread as an unsafe pointer. On the other hand, I might have this completely wrong. I have tried to find some authoritative source talking about this, but failed. Can anyone explain what the runtime does in this case?

btw: We are swaping the `Dictionary` for a `ConcurrentDictionary` anyway, so no need for alarm.

Comment: I'm not sure why they would call it a `static` dictionary but `unsafe` probably refers to not thread-safe. Switch to the Concurrent version ASAP and see what remains of the report.

Comment: BTW: there are no unsafe pointers/references in this code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Thanks for the comment. So how is the `Dictionary` shared between processes/threads? The `Dictionary` is in the managed heap of the main thread, how does it get to the thread executing the `Task`?

Comment: You call `responseDictionary.Add()` from the Task. The variable is being 'closed over' or 'captured'.

Comment: And the Heap belongs to all threads.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Sorry, I don't understand. Any idea what the CLR actually does in memory?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - To all threads inside the process, no? From my understanding, the thread pool, where `Task` threads are taken from, belongs to another process.

Comment: The ThreadPool very much belongs to 1 process. And so does the Heap.

Comment: And [C# Closures Explained](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Thanks for the clarification. Care to sum it all up in an answer so I can give you credit? :)

Comment: What monitoring software is this and what message does it give exactly? This issue is very nebulous to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does a dictionary get passed byref to a Task

A Dictionary is a reference type so it doesn't matter too much if it is passed by-value or by-ref. But as it happens closure is mostly like by-ref.

In your code:

```
Dictionary<string, WSResponse> responseDictionary = ...;

  Task newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
       WSResponse response = Query.GetListFor(localID);                    
       responseDictionary.Add(localID, response);
  });
```

The dictionary is declared outside the scope of the Task lambda but the lambda does use it by name. This is allowed and called ['closing over'](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained) the variable.

And that means that multiple threads can access your Dictionary and it should be replaced by a ConcurrentDictionary. Most likely that will solve the diagnostic message.

Comment: Thank you! The link you provided about 'closing over' was exactly the info I was looking for. You learn something new every day :)